# How to get values from a list inside a json object via python and mongodb?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a mongodb db that has the following structure:

```
"addr1": {

"hostname": { "-name": "x" },
"os": {
  "-version": "x",
  "-acc": "x"
},
"ports":{ 
   "PORTNUMY" : {

    "service": "x",
    "version": "x"
  },
  "PORTNUMX" : {

    "service": "s",
    "version": "v"
  }
}
```

}

formed by the following registers:

```
{"ip": "X.X.X.X", "os accuracy": "96", "hostname": "control0.dnssw.net", "os": "Juniper SA2500 SSL VPN gateway", "ports": [{"product": "na", "version": "na", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "25", "service": "smtp"}, {"product": "na", "version": "na", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "80", "service": "http"}, {"product": "na", "version": "na", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "443", "service": "http"}, {"product": "na", "version": "na", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "465", "service": "smtps"}, {"product": "na", "version": "na", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "993", "service": "imaps"}, {"product": "na", "version": "na", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "995", "service": "pop3s"}]}
```

I'm using this in python to look for a register that matches a certain IP addr:

```
todos = db.mapa.find({'addr': 'X.X.X.X'})
```

What I want is to check how many ip's have for example the port 80 open.

Any ideas? I started with json and mongodb using python just today I googled but I can't find anything straight to the point.

Many thanks!

Comment: you can use python `json` module here.

Comment: how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your above json structure :

```
import json
jobj = json.loads(input_data)
port_count = 0
for i in jobj['ports']:
    if int(i['port']) == 80:
        port_count += 1
>>> print(port_count)
1
```